# Angular - Focus on input element that has ngIf

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have two input elements that are shown under `*ngIf` conditions.

```
<input type="text" id="textInput" *ngIf="showTextInput">
<input type="number" id="numericInput" *ngIf="showNumericInput">

<button (click)="editButtonClicked($event)">
```

Clicking on the button should set focus to the appropriate input element.

```
editButtonClicked(event) {
  // Focus on either #textInput or #numericInput element
}
```

I've looked into **ElementRef** to give the html input elements tags like `#textInput` and then define them on the class for example:

```
@ViewChild('textInput') textInput: ElementRef;
```

...but apparently this does not work on elements that have `*ngIf` conditionals.

**How can I focus on an input element, onClick of a button?**

Comment: Do you want to set focus on `textInput` on button click?

Comment: use some timeout with ElementRef, hope it will help you.

Comment: @PrashantPimpale correct, I would like to set focus on the `textInput` on button click.

Comment: @bruh Have you tried posted answers? Does that help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could implement a super simple directive and have the desired effect.

**html**

```
<input type="text" autoFocus *ngIf="isInputVisible">
```

**directive**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
  selector: "[autoFocus]"
})
export class AutoFocusDirective implements OnInit {
  private inputElement: HTMLElement;

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
    this.inputElement = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.inputElement.focus();
  }
}
```

**Working Demo:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vvgcch?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdirectives%2Fauto-focus.directive.ts

Answer (score 1):

Yes `@ViewChild` will not work for elements who are under the control of a structural directive. There are two workaround that you can apply:

1. Remove the `*ngIf` directive and hide the element using CSS `style: 'display:none'`.
2. Select the element from the DOM using vanilla Javascript `document.getElementById('someId');` and then focus the element.

I will prefer point 1.

Answer (score 1):

you can also do this by template reference variable if that's what you are looking for

**in html**

```
<input #text type="text" id="textInput">
<input #number type="number" id="numericInput">

<button (click)="editButtonClicked($event, text, number)"> Click </button>
```

**in ts**

```
editButtonClicked(e, text, number){
    if(text.value) {
      text.focus()
    } else {
      number.focus()
    }
  }
```

Comment: Usman, as the input is under a *ngIf, you need change the value of the variable and, in a setTimeout make the focus -it's necesary the setTimeout to give time to Angular to show the element-

Comment: Thanks for your response usman, as Eliseo mentioned - due to the `*ngIf` conditional, this solution would require something like a setTimeout. I consider `setTimeout()` to be a rather hacky solution, so I will avoid that.